# Chromium based mobile browser prompting users before download preventing script to run

Tags: node.js, express

I'm generating a `.ics` file after a user POST request. The file gets downloaded correctly tho on Chromium mobile browsers (eg: Chrome/Firefox) the user get prompt a second time (by the browser) to download it.

That behaviour is breaking the rest of the request (eg: deleting the file once it has been downloaded).

It seems like chrome is intercepting the request emanating from the website and making an actual download request on its own. This doesn't happen on Safari mobile.

Would anyone have a bypass/fix/idea for controlling that behaviour? Something that would work on both mobile and desktop?

Following are my ajax POST request and express Routing

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/form',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    success: (response) => {
        console.log('you got something back...');
        $.each(response, () => {
            window.location.replace(`./${aeroclub}/${stamp}`);
        });
    },
    error: (err) => {
        console.log(err);
    },
    complete: console.log('data successfully sent...'),
});
```

```
app.get(['/:download',], (request, response) => {
    let stamp = request.params.stamp;
    console.log(`visiting the response url for download :: ${stamp}...`);
    response.download(resolve(`${__dirname}/ics/${stamp}.ics`), () => {
        fs.unlink(`./ics/${stamp}.ics`, error => {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error);
            };
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently bypassing the issue by setting a unique identifier per user and deleting all files with that unique identifier at the beginning of the POST request.

Tho this implies keeping 1 version of a file per user at any time.